# En una tabla de MYSQL, no se inserta un valor correctamente

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, mvc

Estoy trabajando en un sistema que guarda los detalles de una factura, el valor el cual tengo el problema es el de moneda_usada, el problema es que no coloca la moneda correctamente, duplica la ultima moneda que el secretario coloco en vez de colocar ambas

[image: Asi es como se van a insertar los datos]

Aqui es como sale en la base de datos, como pueden ver simplemente clona la ultima moneda y se la coloca al anterior

[image: Como pueden ver, puso Euro dos veces]

En global.js.tpl, tengo esta funcion que agarra los datos del HTML para convertirlo en valores en PHP

```
function save(print) {

    var numeroFilas = $("#tablaMetodosPago tbody tr").length;
    if (numeroFilas <= 0) {
        swal("¡Error!","Se debe seleccionar al menos un metodo de pago","error");
    }else{

        var engargadoDeVentas = document.getElementById("idCreador").value;
        try {
            var elementoIdCreador = document.querySelector(`#busqueda option[value="${engargadoDeVentas}"]`).dataset.value;
        }catch(error) {
            var elementoIdCreador = null;
        }

        if (elementoIdCreador == null) {
            swal("¡Error!","Se debe seleccionar al responsable de la venta","error");
        }else {
            var idElementos = [
                document.getElementsByClassName("idPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("cantidadPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("sesionesPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("idDetallePaquete"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("idPagos"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("precioPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("descuentoPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("totalPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("impuestoPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("montosPagos"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("duracionPaquetes"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("impuesto_no"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("tipoCompra"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("referenciasPagos"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("fechasCompras"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("fechasActivaciones"),
                document.getElementsByClassName("fechasVencimientos")
            ];
            var resultElementos = [];

            for(let indice= 0; indice<idElementos.length; indice++) {
                let elemento = idElementos[indice];
                let newElemento = [];
                for(let iteracion= 0; iteracion<elemento.length; iteracion++){

                    if (indice < 5 ) {
                        let idElemento = elemento[iteracion].innerHTML;
                        if(idElemento) {
                            idElemento = parseInt(idElemento);
                            newElemento.push(idElemento);
                        }

                    } else if (indice > 4 && indice < 10 ) {
                        let idElemento = numeral(elemento[iteracion].innerHTML);
                        if(idElemento) {
                            idElemento = idElemento.value();
                            newElemento.push(idElemento);
                        }

                    } else if (indice > 9 && indice < 14 ) {
                        let idElemento = elemento[iteracion].innerHTML;
                        newElemento.push(idElemento);

                    } else if (indice > 13) {
                        let idElemento = moment(elemento[iteracion].innerHTML,'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        if(idElemento) {
                            newElemento.push(idElemento);
                        }
                    }
                }
                resultElementos.push(newElemento);
            }

            datos = { 
                "opcion"  : "save",
                "elementoId": resultElementos[0],
                "elementoCantidad": resultElementos[1],
                "elementoSesiones": resultElementos[2],
                "elementoIdDettallePaquete": resultElementos[3],
                "elementoIdPago": resultElementos[4],
                "elementoPrecio": resultElementos[5],
                "elementoDescuento": resultElementos[6],
                "elementoTotal": resultElementos[7],
                "elementoImpuestoMonto": resultElementos[8],
                "elementoMontoPago": resultElementos[9],
                "elementoDuracion": resultElementos[10],
                "elementoImpuestoNo": resultElementos[11],
                "elementoTipo": resultElementos[12],
                "elementoReferenciaPago": resultElementos[13],
                "elementoFechaCompra": resultElementos[14],
                "elementoFechaActiva": resultElementos[15],
                "elementoFechaVencimiento": resultElementos[16],
                "elementoIdUsuario": $("#Usuario").val(),
                elementoIdCreador,
                "elementoCentroUsuario": $('#centroLogin').val(),
                "elementoAccesoUsuario": parseInt($("#usuarioAcceso").val()),
                "elementoPrecioNeto": parseFloat($("#facturas_subtotal").val()),
                "elementoPrecioTotal": parseFloat($("#facturas_total").val()),
                "elementomonedaUsar": $("#monedaUsar").val()
            };


            $.ajax({

                url: '../controllers/facturacionController.php',

                type: 'POST',

                data: datos,

                success: function(data){  

                    var success = JSON.parse(data).success; 
                    var msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
                    var Id_factura = JSON.parse(data).Id_factura;
                    if(success){
                        swal("¡Realizado!", msj, "success").then((value) => {
                            if (print) {
                                window.print(Id_factura);
                            }else{
                                location.href = 'dashboard.php';   
                            } 
                        });

                    }else{

                        swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");

                    }
                }
            });


        }  
    }
}
```

Esto se conecta a un modelo llamado FacturacionModel, el cual posee la siguiente funcion save, en donde tengo problemas es cuando tiene que hacer INSERT en detalle_pago

```
public function save($datos){  

    require '../require/Conexion.php';

        $numProductos = sizeof($datos["elementoId"]);
        $numPagos = sizeof($datos["elementoIdPago"]);
        $sqlPaqueteCliente = array();
        $sqlPaqueteCliente = array();
        $sqlDetallePago = array();
        $sqlDetalleFactura = array();
        $id_paquete = sizeof($datos["elementoId"]);
        $id_usuario = $datos["elementoIdUsuario"];
        $id_centro = $datos["elementoCentroUsuario"];
        $id_acceso = $datos["elementoAccesoUsuario"];
        $nombre = $datos["elementomonedaUsar"];
        $id_creador = $datos["elementoIdCreador"];
        $precioNeto = $datos["elementoPrecioNeto"];
        $precioTotal = $datos["elementoPrecioTotal"];
        $create_by = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
        $cantidad_clases = array(); 
        $tipo_compra = array(); 
        $cantidad_total = array(); 
        $fecha_compra = array();
        $fecha_activacion = array();
        $fecha_vencimiento = array();
        $impuestoNo = array();
        $impuestoMonto = array();
        $referenciaPago = array();
        $resultPaqueteCliente = array();
        $resultDetallePago = array();
        $resultDetalleFactura = array();
        $id_formapago = array();
        $monto_metodopago = array();
        $fechaActual =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
        $idDetallePaquete = array();
        $descuentoPaquete = array();
        $precioPaquete = array();
        $totalPaquete = array();
        $cantidadPaquete = array();
        $id_detallefactura = array();

        //seleccionar el id del impuesto utilizado
        $sqlImpuesto = "SELECT im.id_impuesto FROM ec_impuesto AS im WHERE im.id_centro = '".$id_centro."';";
        $resultImpuesto = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlImpuesto);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImpuesto);
        $id_impuesto = $row["id_impuesto"];
        mysqli_free_result($resultImpuesto);

        $sqlFactura = "
            INSERT INTO `ec_facturacion`(`id_usuario`, `id_impuesto`,`id_encargado_venta`,`id_create_by`,
            `numero_factura`, `fecha_factura`, `precio_neto`, `precio_total`,`operation`) 
            VALUES ('".$id_usuario."','".$id_impuesto."','".$id_creador."','".$create_by."',
            '','".$fechaActual."','".$precioNeto."','".$precioTotal."','INSERT');
        ";
        $resultFactura = @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlFactura);

        if($resultFactura == false){
            return null;
        }

        $id_factura = $mysqli->insert_id;

        for($p = 0 ; $p < $numPagos ; $p++){

            array_push($id_formapago, $datos["elementoIdPago"][$p]);

            array_push($monto_metodopago, $datos["elementoMontoPago"][$p]); 

            array_push($referenciaPago, $datos["elementoReferenciaPago"][$p]);

            array_push($nombre, $datos["elementomonedaUsar"][$p]);


            array_push($sqlDetallePago,"
                INSERT INTO `ec_detalle_pago`(`id_formapago`, `id_factura`, `moneda_usada`, `cantidad`,`referencia_pago`) 
                VALUES ('".$id_formapago[$p]."','".$id_factura."','".$nombre."','".$monto_metodopago[$p]."','".$referenciaPago[$p]."');
            ");

            array_push($resultDetallePago, @mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlDetallePago[$p]));// or die(mysqli_error($conn));

            if($resultDetallePago[$p] == false){
                return null;
            }
        }
```

La funcion save del facturacioncontroller hace lo siguiente, solamente lo guarda. Estoy seguro que debo tener un problema en el modelo ya que si guarda los datos pero clona la moneda, pero el resto funciona perfecto

```
function save($datos){

        $factura = new facturaModel;

        $json = array();

        $Id_factura = $factura->save($datos);

        if($Id_factura != null){


            $json['msj'] = 'La factura ha sido creada exitosamente'; 
            $json['success'] = true;
            $json['Id_factura'] = $Id_factura;
            echo json_encode($json);

        }else{

            $json['msj'] = 'Error . No se pudo relaizar la factura'; 
            $json['success'] = false;
            echo json_encode($json);

        } 


    }
```

Comment: en tu metodo save, $nombre (que es donde guardaste las monedas) no es un array? y por lo tanto no deberia ser $nombre[$p]?

Comment: Voy a intentar eso

Comment: Lo intente y no me muestra la moneda completa, muestra la "D" de dolar o la "E" de Euro en vez del nombre entero

Comment: Bueno! ya resolviste tu problema.. ahora porque viene una D o E, es por lo que mandas desde el front.. pero ya graba lo que corresponde ;)

Comment: Hay alguna forma de traerse el nombre completo? Intente sizeof y se rompio

Comment: ya tanto no te puedo ayudar.. ni idea que viene desde tu front end.. ahora vas a tener que revisar esa parte...

Comment: Una cosa que me llama la atención es que en tu variable `datos` de Javascript hay un elemento huérfano: `elementoIdCreador,` ese elemento no tiene su par asignado como todos los los demás ¿a qué se debe eso? En cuanto al servidor, si mostraras en la pregunta el resultado de un `var_dump($datos);` quizá podamos ver mejor lo que está llegando.

Comment: Ya arreglue el problema, faltaban unos metodos por alli